# Razor form submitting only a single input field

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am creating a simple form in Razor Page, it's sending the form values back to frontend but when I use the same values at backend they are null.

[image: Frontend]
[image: Backend]

```html
    <form method="POST" class="form form--login">
      <fieldset class="card card--login">
        <legend>Login</legend>

        <input aria-label="username" name="Username" type="text" title="Username can't be empty." placeholder="Username"
        class="input input--text" />

        <input aria-label="password" name="Password" type="password" title="Password is required." placeholder="Password"
        class="input input--text" />

        <input aria-label="Test" name="Test" type="datetime-local" title="Test is required." placeholder="Test"
        class="input input--text" />
      </fieldset>

      <button type="submit" class="button button--submit">Submit</button>
    </form>


@* Using this to check for values after form submission *@
@Model.Username
@Model.Password
@Model.Test
```

```cs
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Test { get; set; }

    Username = Request.Form["Username"];
    Password = Request.Form["Password"];
    Test = Request.Form["Test"];

    Console.WriteLine(Username, Password, Test);
```

Comment: what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: How are you getting data back? Put that code in your question.

Comment: @शेखर You can now see at bottom of CSHTML that I am using `@Model.*` to print the values of submitted fields

Comment: @NegiRox I'm just trying to get the values submitted in form inputs.

Comment: @HimanshuPal unabe to see razor syntax

Comment: Is your project an mvc project or a razor-pages project?Is this asp.net core project?

Comment: @NegiRox Yeah, not using `asp-for` or `@HTML` just trying to keep it minimal as possible. But it should also work like this right ?

Comment: @Yinqiu Yes, It's ASP.NET Core project using Razor pages syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your PageModel like following:

```
 public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
  
    [BindProperty]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public string Test { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {

        return Page();
    }
}
```

Your page:

```
@page
@model IndexModel

<form method="POST" class="form form--login">
    <fieldset class="card card--login">
        <legend>Login</legend>

        <input aria-label="username" name="Username" type="text" title="Username can't be empty." placeholder="Username"
               class="input input--text" />

        <input aria-label="password" name="Password" type="password" title="Password is required." placeholder="Password"
               class="input input--text" />

        <input aria-label="Test" name="Test" type="datetime-local" title="Test is required." placeholder="Test"
               class="input input--text" />
    </fieldset>

    <button type="submit" class="button button--submit">Submit</button>
</form>
@Model.Username
@Model.Password
@Model.Test
```

Test Result:

[image]

For more details,you can learn this [article](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding).

Comment: Please share your pagemodel and your page.

Comment: The error is solved now.
It was that JS is my primary language so I'm used to console logging multiple things at once `console.log(...args)` & I just realized that it's not possible with `Console.WriteLine(...args)` with same syntax.

Anyway thanks for your time. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Try with Form keyword remove.

```
var Username = Request["Username"].ToString(); 
var Password = Request["Password"].ToString(); 
var Test = Request["Test"].ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks, facing another error using this `error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'HttpRequest'`